# How to load recaptcha code only when jQuery dialog loads

Tags: jquery, recaptcha

I have a recaptcha code within a jQuery dialog.

For some reason, when I load the page in firefox, it hangs (works great on IE/Chrome though).
I found that the recaptcha in the dialog is causing it.

I thought that if I would load the recaptcha code only when a user opens the dialog that might solve the issue and also help me reduce the amount of outbound connections in general.

this is the 'view source' of the bit that is related to the recaptcha:

```
<div id="dialog-form" title="Create new user"> 
    <p class="validateTips">You can also Connect with Facebook</p> 
    <fb:login-button perms="publish_stream,create_event,rsvp_event,user_birthday,user_events,user_hometown,user_location,user_online_presence">Login to Facebook</fb:login-button> 
    <form id="regform" action="" method="post"> 
    <fieldset> 
        <label for="name">Username</label> 
        <input type="text" name="username" id="name" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" value="" /> 
        <label for="email">Email</label> 
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" value="" /> 
        <label for="password" style="float:left;">Password&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label> 
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" /> 
        <input type="hidden" name="reg" value="reg" /> 
    </fieldset> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=6LerjL4SAAAAAG3sq_40sHyvch501El5JoNkHqOR"></script> 

    <noscript> 
        <iframe src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=6LerjL4SAAAAAG3sq_40sHyvch501El5JoNkHqOR" height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br/>
        <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea>
        <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field" value="manual_challenge"/>
    </noscript>     </form> 
</div>
```

it's placed at the bottom of the page, right before the  tag, so it's not nested or anything.

How can I do it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you plan on using reCaptcha in a popup-dialog, I would strongly suggest using the [javascript api](http://wiki.recaptcha.net/index.php/Overview#AJAX_API). I've found that FireFox can have trouble handling the iframe in such situations.

After you receive a call to open the dialog in the client-side javascript, you call for the creation of the captcha like this:

```
Recaptcha.create(YOUR_API_KEY,
    "captcha_contain",
    {
    theme: "red",
    callback: Recaptcha.focus_response_field
    }
);
```

Where "captcha_contain" is the id of an element in your dialog, presumably an open div.
It will change your server-side code somewhat too, but you can read all about that in the API.

Comment: But i'm using a normal jQuery modal dialog, without an iframe, is that still a problem?

Comment: Well, the recaptcha `<script>` tag that you have generates an iframe (that's what I meant). Sometimes, when first hiding the frame and then moving it around and showing it again (which jquery dialog does) causes problems - it's better to use the ajax protocol. I don't know whether it'll solve your specific problem, but it's worth a try.

Comment: Oh, now I see what you mean. OK, i'll give it a try and let you know, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

[This thread](http://groups.google.com/group/recaptcha/browse_thread/thread/6d106a38fe348ae9?pli=1) suggests that it might be due to invalid HTML.
In that case it was because a `<form>` was placed inside of a `<table>`.
Might that be your case as well?

Anyhow, if you really want to load the captcha just on dialog open you will have to get the content through AJAX.
Use the [open](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#event-open) event in jQuery UI Dialog to decide when to retrieve your captcha.
I'm not familiar with the API of reCaptcha, but maybe there is an Javascript API, otherwise you will have to let your PHP code render that captcha for you on a separate page (or in some way expose it to the client).

Comment: My captcha code looks something like this: <div><p>some text</p><form><input /><?php echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey); ?></form> is that valid?

Comment: validated my code through validator.w3.org, seems fine other than just a few missing alt tags for images.. When I load the page on firefox, it shows up for a second, then it shows a blank screen and shows "Waiting for google.com" at the status bar (recaptcha api files are hosted on google.com as far as i know). If I comment out the recaptcha echo line, everything is back to normal.

Comment: Well... as Peter Forss said, we're really going to need to see some code to do further troubleshooting as there doesn't seem to be enough context to work out a possible solution. Keep in mind that if the original code is private or proprietary you can just create a contrived example for us which manifests the same error. =o)

Comment: Exactly, and what is interesting is the rendered code ("view source"), not the serverside (you are showing up the PHP code that generates your captcha). And we also need to know what version of Firefox you are using etc..

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem with reCAPTCHA and Firefox 3.6. On a side note, the same code worked great with IE and Chrome. After much debugging (and some tips from the answers above) I found that the `<fieldset>` tag inside my form was causing jquery to crash.

Simply removing the `<fieldset>` and the error went away.

Hope it helps others out there.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this issue, again just in FF3.6 when using a lightbox — loading the reCatpcha div into the page but hiding it until onSubmit of the form.

Resolved the issue by using 'visibility: hidden' on the reCaptcha form rather than 'display: none'.

(Simple fix, but a pain at the time — just in case it's of use to anyone else :) )